# jQuery Reload current page after return from MVC Controller Action called from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some code in Global.asax that I need executed after a jQuery call to a Controller Action that performs some logic. I need to reload the current page (whatever that page is) after the Controller Action returns.

**jQuery call to Controller Action**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#SelectedLanguage').on('change', function () {
            var culture = $(this).val();
            $('#test').load("/Account/TestPartial/" + culture);
            //location.reload(true);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller Action /Account/TestPartial**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult TestPartial(string id)
{
    SetLanguage(id);

    var model = new LanguageListPartialViewModel();

    model.Languages = GetLanguageList();
    model.SelectedLanguage = id;

    return View(model);
}
```

I tried `location.reload(true);` but it reloads immediately. I need to wait until the Controller Action returns. Tried to implement `await` in the Controller Action, but I guess I'm not sure how to code that since none of the called routines inside of TestPartial return anything compatible with `await`.

jQuery .get() seems to be an option? Does these mean I would have to convert the jQuery calling parameter to JSON and also code the Controller Action for JSON, or is there a way to make the call as-is using .get()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to reload the page after a bit of AJAX returns, there's no point in using AJAX. Just do a normal GET or POST.

That said, your problem here is that AJAX is asynchronous. In other words, after the line `$('#test').load(...)` is executed, the next line is immediately executed, before the whole AJAX bit has had a chance to send the request and receive the response. In order to execute code only after the response has returned, you have to pass a callback:

```
$('#test').load('/Account/TestPartial/' + culture, function () {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Nice. That easy... It works that way Chris. Thx for your help.

Comment: Chris, it seems that a cookie that needs to be written in the Controller Action no longer gets written. Would the page reload be preventing the `Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)` from getting set?